# Magento 2 Luma Checkout Problem with logged in Users

Tags: magento2, checkout, luma-theme, checkout-page

We made a Magento 2 Parent-Theme based on Luma and we changed some css styles, it still working but we have Problems with the Checkout.

My Testside: http://staging.meat4you.ch

- 1) If some registered User is Logged-In, go to some Items, put these Items to the Shipping Card and click to Checkout - After that, the Checkout Page is not complete loaded (look the printscreen).

Its only show a white page with the Card, but the Addresses and Buttons for next Steps are missing.

- 2) If you are a Guest User, it works perfect!
- 3) If you go to Checkout and only Logged-In in the Checkout Page, its works perfect!

[image]

Somebody can help me to solve this Problem with registered Users and Logged-In before Checkout?
Thank you very much.

PS: Sorry, for the Picture Puzzle, stagexchange allow only 2 Links.

Comment: I try to reproduce it and I cannot

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, KAndy. Do you logged in first and after go to checkout, do you see the whitepage?

Comment: try disabling all 3rd party modules and check if the problem still persists

Comment: My Solution for this Problem: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4921

just in case if store configuration for customer address is 2 or more street lines then rules.js gives the error. Change store configuration in:
Stores > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options: Number of Lines in a Street Address make it 1.